# Session NullReferenceException error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I'm using below code within MVC controller class. My question is: when I attempt to run the code, I get the following error.

> NullReferenceException

Code:

```
if (Session["User"] != null)
{
     return true;
}
```

What am I wrong? What is the problem misunderstood related with session?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Session is null, presumably because you don't have a session state provider configured or because it's not available at the point that you're making the call (such as in the constructor).

Try [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759795/c-cannot-check-session-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Well, try first init session in global.asax. Just add this code to global.asax

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```