# Checking session exists or not- mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, controller

I was googling on Sessions and mvc3, and I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759795/c-sharp-cannot-check-session-exists/759818#759818). To that question a [marc-gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) answered

> The session only really exists during the processing of an action - I
>   wouldn't expect it to be valid in the constructor of a controller. For
>   example, the controller might (for all I know) be re-used between
>   requests.

I think that may not be the case by reading further on mvc requests and creation of controller, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5426118/2098335):

> A Controller is created for every request by the ControllerFactory
>   (which by default is the DefaultControllerFactory).

So I think, Marc was incorrect and we can simply check the Session exist or not from controller's constructor.

In short, should I follow [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759818/2098335), or not? Or is there any better way to check sessions with mvc?

Comment: Not everyone uses the default factories... Making an assumption that such things are per-request could be very dangerous.

Comment: @MarcGravell But I think that is the default behavior of MVC

Comment: yes, but you should *design* for what is the *allowed* behavior of MVC

Comment: @MarcGravell: So you are saying that, controller should not be created with each request? How can I achieve that?

Comment: I didn't say "should not"; I am trying to make the point that it *might not*, and that your code shouldn't make assumptions about that. The "How can I achieve that?" is simply: *provide your own factory*